# Docker build on tensorflow version 2.4.3 gives out public key errors

Tags: docker, tensorflow, ssh-keys

i am trying to build a docker from the tensorflow dockerhub, using tensorflow version 2.4.3, i did a simple pull and docker file:

```
$ docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.2-gpu
```

And here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.3-gpu

ADD . /path
WORKDIR /path

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install sudo
```

However i get errors on the apt-get update line:

```
$ docker build -t tensorflow_gpu_build .

...

Step 4/10 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in 7c67f26124cb
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease [1581 B]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [1573 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]
Err:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
The following signatures couldn''t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [3145 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1371 kB]
Ign:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1412 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [22.9 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [2351 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [3568 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.8 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages [64.0 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [20.5 kB]
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease: The following signatures couldn''t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC
E: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease' is no longer signed.
```

I am unsure of where the problem is coming from, the same dockerfile worked fine on the latest tensorfow docker version, could it be normal behaviour because the tensorflow version is a little old?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the key included in the image has been revoked by Nvidia in the meantime.

So, you have three possibilities:

1. You can check for a valid pub key for that repository, copy it to the image via Dockerfile and add it with this command:

   apt-key add /path/to/key
2. You can add an "[ allow-insecure=yes ]" to the respective line in the /etc/apt/sources.list as elaborated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198000/bypass-gpg-signature-checks-only-for-a-single-repository
3. You could try a newer image.

Comment: I was allowed to update apt-get with the option -o Acquire::AllowDowngradeToInsecureRepositories=true, it is not required on the other lines afterward, thanks